# Error when downloading application from the play store: RPC: S-3

Tags: google-play-store

I just got an Android tablet and when I try to install an app on the Play store it says:

> error retrieving information from server [RPC:S-3].

I've tried clearing the data for the Play Store app & turning it off & back on but it didn't work.

Answer (score 12):

1. Try going Settings>Accounts>Google>Tap your account> tap three dots in the upper right (or press menu button) "Remove Account".
2. Go to "Settings"->“Applications”->“Manage Applications”
3. Select "All"
4. Scroll to and tap “Google Play Store”
5. Tap “Force Stop”, tap “OK”, tap “Clear data”, and tap "OK".
6. Tap the Back button to get back to the applications list.
7. Scroll to and tap “Google Service Framework” (or Google Play Services)
8. Tap “Force Stop”, tap “OK”, tap “Clear data”, and tap "OK".

Now reboot (switch on & off) your device.

Comment: Try going Settings>Accounts>Google> Tap your account> Three dots in the upper right (or press menu button) "Remove Account" ... then read your account .. then if you want, clear Play store cache and data and try it. 

Worked for me!

Comment: +1, why don't they just invent a button that recomputes all caches. hilarious.